# Android - Create expand/collapse layout in Fragment extension

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I try to create expandable layout in `Fragment` extension. Unfortunately after adding some actions to `onCreateView()` method, it show an error "Unfortunately app has stopped". I have no idea how to solve this problem to show layout without errors.

This is the class with `Fragment` extension:

```
public class MainPage extends Fragment{

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    LinearLayout linearLayoutHeader;
    ValueAnimator animator;

    public MainPage(){

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInsatnceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page, container, false);        

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        linearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.header);

        //Add onPreDrawListener
        linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                linearLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                animator = slideAnimator(0, linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                return true;
            }
        });



        linearLayoutHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (linearLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    expand();
                }else{
                    collapse();
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

Probably there's an error in calling this three lines, but I can't find it:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page, container, false);        

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        linearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.header);
```

And this is the log:

```
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.worlddelegation/com.example.worlddelegation.Glowna}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at com.example.worlddelegation.MainPage.onCreateView(MainPage.java:30)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
12-27 12:55:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(896):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateView your view is being created and as such getView() will still return a null.  You need to change the two lines to:

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.expandable);
linearLayoutHeader = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.header);
```

Where v is the view you just inflated.